# How do I train a code that the label is also a image?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do a image denoising code ,so my image is noised image and my label is clean image.I already put all image into a .tfrecords file.Now when I traing ,I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tian/tensorflow/example/Denoising/Try_Myself/train.py", line 59, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/tian/tensorflow/example/Denoising/Try_Myself/train.py", line 54, in main
    img_noised,img_gray=get_batch(image1, image2, batch_size)
  File "/home/tian/tensorflow/example/Denoising/Try_Myself/ops.py", line 64, in get_batch
    num_threads=16, capacity=5000, min_after_dequeue=1000,)
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 1220, in shuffle_batch
    name=name)
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 776, in _shuffle_batch
    dtypes=types, shapes=shapes, shared_name=shared_name)
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 629, in __init__
    shapes = _as_shape_list(shapes, dtypes)
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 76, in _as_shape_list
    raise ValueError("All shapes must be fully defined: %s" % shapes)
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)])]
```

It said something wrong in here:

```
def get_batch(image, label, batch_size):
    images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 num_threads=16, capacity=5000, min_after_dequeue=1000,)

    #return images, tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])
    return images, label_batch
```

the return images is noised image,and label_batch is clean image.
Please, someone tell me how to fix it that I can train this code belong those command：

```
‘’‘’‘’
for i in range(Train_step):
     image_noised,image_clean=sess.run([train_X,train_Y])
     print('Shape',image_gray.shape)
     _,loss_value,step=sess.run([train_op,loss,global_step],feed_dict=　{X:image_noised, X_:image_gray})
‘’‘’‘’
```

Ps: the image shape is [180,180,1],and batch_size is 8. Any information if you need,please tell me.

The code that read .tfrecords file is :

```
def read_and_decode(filename):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])  

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)  
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
                                       features={
                                           'image_raw_gray': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                           'image_raw_noised': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                       })

    img_g = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw_gray'], tf.uint8)
    img_n = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw_noised'], tf.uint8)

    image_g = tf.cast(img_g, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
    image_n = tf.cast(img_n, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5

    return image_g, image_n
```

The code that I create the .tfrecords file is here:

```
''''''
''''''
img_gray=cv2.imread(gray_img)
img_noised=cv2.imread(noised_img)

img_raw_gray=img_gray.tobytes()
img_raw_noised=img_noised.tobytes()

example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image_raw_gray': _bytes_feature(img_raw_gray),
    'image_raw_noised': _bytes_feature(img_raw_noised),
    'height': _int64_feature(img_gray.shape[0]),
    'width': _int64_feature(img_gray.shape[1]),
}))
'''''''
'''''''
```

Comment: Can you print the shape of `images` and `label_batch` just before the return of `get_batch`?

Comment: The image shape what I input to get_batch is (?,). I don't know what it mean. And I already add  the code that read .tfrecords file named 'read_and_decode(filename)'

Comment: From what I see in your input code, you store the images in your tfrecord files already decoded. Is this true?

Comment: Actually, in my files, I use .tobytes() to transform image into bytes like 'img=image.tobytes()', and than store it with 'example=tf.train.Example(...)'. But it seams do not decode it in files...

Comment: And I assume `image` is a numpy array, right?
I'm asking because the typical way to go would be to store the byte content of the file (as in, open file as binary, `read()` and store the result in the `Example`) ad then decode the file in TF via `tf.train.decode_image`.

Comment: I already give the code that I create the .tfrecords file . Do I get some wrong in this code? Please take a look~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### About your error

Shape `(?,)` means that you have a one-dimensional vector of unspecified length.
Since you store the pre-decoded images in your `TFRecord`s, `tf.decode_raw` cannot know what shape your image originally had.
You need to put an `img_g = tf.reshape(img_g, (180, 180, 1))` right after your `decode_raw` call to fix this problem.

#### About your tfrecords

The way you build the TFRecord files is a bit odd. Firstly, since you're storing the raw, decoded bytes for each image, your examples are rather heavy.

Secondly, you're relying on the decoded data from opencv to be directly compatible with Tensorflow (as in, same representation of the data). This is usually the case, although if you were to use 3-channel images you might run into problems.

To fix both problems at the same time, you should instead write in your `tf.train.Example` the bytes contained in the image files, i.e., the **encoded** image, which you then decode in tensorflow:

```
# in your file to create tfrecords
with open(gray_img, 'rb') as fp:
  img_gray_encoded = fp.read()
with open(noised_img, 'rb') as fp:
  img_noised_encoded = fp.read()

example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image_encoded_gray': _bytes_feature(img_gray_encoded),
    'image_encoded_noised': _bytes_feature(img_noised_encoded)
}))
```

Note that I'm removing the width and height features, since that is already implicitly defined in the encoded image.

```
# in the input pipeline
img_g = tf.image.decode_image(features['image_gray_encoded'], channels=1)
tf.set_shape(img_g, (180, 180, 1))

img_n = tf.image.decode_image(features['image_noised_encoded'], channels=1)
tf.set_shape(img_n, (180, 180, 1))
```

Note that in this case I'm not using `reshape`, but `set_shape`.
This is because, unlike with your example, here `decode_image` knows (**at runtime**) what your image's shape is. To make that shape available at graph construction time, we *inform* tensorflow that the image actually has always shape `(180, 180, 1)`.

Comment: You are right! But the code is still didn't work. And it still wrong in 'get_batch(image, label, batch_size)' of my code.The error is like this:"OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 8, current size 0)
  [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]". Don you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Frank.Fan see my update to the answer for more info on your tfrecords.
About the other error, that's another matter entirely and you should probably ask in a separate question. I can already tell you, however, that my guess is that you forgot to start the queue runners.
My suggestion is to replace your input pipeline with one built with the [`tf.contrib.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) API (which is **much** simpler to use)

Comment: Thank you very much ,for your answers. And actually, I use the 'threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)' in my training code, but still get wrong in 'tf.train.shuffle_batch()' .whether it is because the parameters that I set in 'tf.train.shuffle_batch()' ? And, it is a pity that I can't see the detail about the tf.contrib.data API, because I can't over the wall in the network in recently in our country...